Failed to create table in bigquery
After downloading a particular dataset name movies from my Coursera studies hands on activities for my BigQuery exercise, then trying to create table before cleaning the dataset i got an error message saying:

failed to create table: field name 'Director (1) is not supported by
the current character map. Please change your field name or use
character map V2 to let the system modify the field names

where can i find the option to enable character map V2 on my windows system?
i tried to find the character map V2 to enable it so i cxan go ahead and create my table,
i tried to edit the dataset field name but i cant and still getting the error. and i expect the BigQuery to automatically select schema table.

If we look at the docs on BigQuery column names (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names) we find that a column called "Director (1)" is not allowed (Use of parenthesis characters).  Do you have a link or extract from the course instructions you are following?  Is it possible you have accidently introduced these characters?

Does this help?

Changing the column titles from Director (1), Director(2), Cast (1) ... to Director_1, Director_2, Cast_2 ... manually in Excel fixed the problem for me. I assumed that BigQuery does not allow column titles to contain brackets within them.
